# Aligning an empty Div and images

Tags: css

I'm working on a post to get familiar with the Japanese Hiagana. However, I'm going to use a lot more images, and later sound. In order to use fewer images I tried to replace the empty .pngs with a div, but I'm unable to align it with the rest of images. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong in my code, but I really have no idea how to fix it, or if is there an alternative to what I'm doing. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is the page: http://template00test.blogspot.com/2015/03/blog-post.html

```
<style>
.container {
position: relative;
width: 645px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

.miniature {
    width: 6%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 5px;
}

.miniaturex {
    height: 42px;
    width: 6%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px; 
}

</style>
```

miniaturex is the red square in the link above, and it is the one I would like to align with the rest if possible.

This is an example of what I have:

```
<div class="container">

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rMwJbjg8x6I/VRdR9hUt5nI/AAAAAAAACJg/6gs2p1iOtm8/w60-h65-no/ha.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-EyXbRIMgfVI/VRdSBv9N-HI/AAAAAAAACJM/4QC48pQlpvo/w60-h65-no/na.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vz3-ygDqmb0/VRdSFV5Qx4I/AAAAAAAACH0/td8fZFhbqsY/w60-h65-no/ta.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ptiyMClrHPY/VRdSD0q7PxI/AAAAAAAACHU/HG8bUV5D6yQ/w60-h65-no/sa.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-RIuFcb3hvoE/VRdR-br6qFI/AAAAAAAACE4/7y1pcIHMuWU/w60-h65-no/ka.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5hjR44OOz5c/VRdR9QG_maI/AAAAAAAACJg/FI8wRCLD1iI/w60-h65-no/a.png" />

<img class="miniature" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-TWp0rlJ4zXw/VRioHhaQw_I/AAAAAAAACJ8/AUWtqm8hpcU/w60-h65-no/x.png" />

</div> 

<div class="miniaturex"></div>
```

And again, thanks in advance for any help or any clue to an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The Container div is doing a text-align center as well as containing your images to 645 pixels.  The minaturex div is sitting outside of the container, so it's not bound by those styles.

Simply move miniaturex inside the container, or alternatively, duplicate the container div to hold the div.  For clarity's sake, you could also combine common settings on miniature and miniaturex, then have separate CSS declarations for their specific, unique attributes (such as height on minaturex)

Comment: The div is now inside the container, but there is no change. I tried duplicating but I get the same effect, I combined common settings for miniature and miniaturex, and got a separate CSS declaration for miniaturex's height, but remains the same. You can see outcome in the link to nocturnic's reply above. T_T

Answer (score 0):

I would take text-align out of the container.
You could also do something like img .class 
Than call it   `<img class="" />` you could do that to group particular images within the container.

```
<table>
```

`<tr>`

```
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
<td><img src="ra.png" />
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did as suggested, removed the text align center. The div aligns; however, it doesn't allow me to have more images next to it.  Looks like this: http://template00test.blogspot.com/2015/04/no-text-align-center.html I haven't tried with separate classes for each row yet.

Comment: Where do you want the more images

Comment: If you can be a bit more detailed I'll find a solution that works

Comment: Your most clean solution may be build a table

Comment: nocturnics.com right col click family I did that image grouping with a table

Comment: I want to use the div instead of the blank .png squares, the one in the red border is the one I want to use instead of images to reduce the image number because I'm missing other 60 images, but it doesn't align with the rest, could you give me a hint on how to build the table or align as in the post? I'll try with that.

Comment: that table will make them all line up than style them with css